# Can't get ExtJS to write to console

Tags: extjs

I'm just trying to get started with ExtJS, but the documentation isn't very helpful.

I literally have copy&pasted exactly one of their examples, and it won't invoke the controller's `init` function. I even followed there recommended directory layout

*Project Organization:*

```
my_app
  |-- // node.js stuff
  |--public
       |--app
       |   |--controller
       |          |--Users.js
       |
       |--ext-4
       |   |--extjs
       |   |--app.js
       |   |--index.html
       |
       |--app.js
```

*app.js*

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',

    appFolder: 'app',

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Users',
                    html : 'List of users will go here'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

*Users.js*

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
});
```

Which is **exactly** what's in their [getting-started docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture). Page loads&displays, but the controller isn't, and this no output to console. Help?!?? Tried both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Is Users.js script loaded into the browser? Do you have loader enabled?

Comment: @dbrin I'm using the latest version of ExtJS and following the docs **EXACTLY**. This is the code they have - and what they claim should work.

Comment: @dbrin http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: See the first comment under the article :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to start with Ext JS 4.1.3, the current version is 4.2.1. Also, the directory structure is wrong: both `index.html` and `app.js` should be in the top directory:

```
+
|- app +
|      |- controller +
|                    |- Users.js
|- app.js
|- index.html
```

The `appFolder` property in Ext.application call points to a directory *relative* to `index.html`. No magic here.

Comment: Even in the 4.2.1 guide they have app.js and index.html in the ext-4 directory

Comment: @ColinMartell Yes, the screenshot in the guide looks ambiguous indeed. Take a look at the index.html source instead: it loads ext-4/ext-debug.js and app.js relative to where index.html itself is found. When app.js is loaded and executed, it loads all classes from the appFolder, which is relative to index.html too. Look for 404's in the console to get a clue at what goes wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Include this before the app definition:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
```